# Where and how should I place the punctuation marks in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, em-dashes, example

> [James] Iris did not have a job—unless panhandling could be considered one—in which case, he was wholly employed.

How would you place and/or rearrange the punctuation marks in this sentence? I've placed them as well I can, but I'm not still a hundred percent sure that I'm using them correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any quotation marks.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Sorry, brain fart.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you explain the context of the sentence a bit more? Who is "he"? Presumably Iris is female? As it is, the sentence doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Cerberus His name was Iris. James Iris.

Comment: @Cerberus Silly of me, sorry. Iris is the 'he' here.

Comment: The first em dash is fine, but the second one makes it confusing.  How I would write it would be: "Iris did not have a job—unless panhandling could be considered one, in which case he was wholly employed."  To put a comma after "case" isn't a question of grammar but style since short introductory prepositional phrases justify a comma but don't necessarily call for a comma.  Personally, I would omit it because the sentence is already so laden with punctuation that more stands to confuse more than clarify.

Comment: @CaitanyaSingh - You're welcome!  You're welcome!  You're welcome!

Comment: @JasonBassford: Okay, I have never heard of this person.

Answer (score 1):

> [James] Iris did not have a job—unless panhandling could be considered one, in which case he was wholly employed.

There should be no stop immediately after *case*, because *in which case he was wholly employed* is a simple subordinate clause without obvious appositives or other phrases requiring commas. Commas are generally not placed around an (introductory) adverbial phrase if a relative pronoun is part of it, as *which* is here.

There needs to be a comma before *in which case*, because it is the beginning of a non-defining relative clause, which normally requires a comma. The fact that the relative clause begins with *in* rather than *which* doesn't change that.

Before *unless*, there needs to be a stop or dash. The dash indicates an unexpected change in the essential meaning or structure of a sentence, which I think is appropriate here, for the panhandling bit is a somewhat surprising turn. (A comma is possible but somewhat less preferable.)

There should be only one dash in this sentence (if any). Two dashes around a clause or phrase indicate that it is separate from the rest of the sentence and non-essential, like an apposition or parenthesis. But a dash before *in which* is not possible here, because, if you were to remove the *unless* clause, the *in which* clause would be dangling in the air—it is dependent on the *unless* clause. And there can never* be a dash between two elements one of which depends on the other syntactically. The 'unexpected' or parenthetical part, which begins with *unless* and is introduced by the dash, must therefore extend up to and including *employed*, which is at the end of the sentence. There can be no dash at the end of a sentence: the full stop (or other sentence-ending mark) subsumes the function of a dash, comma, or other sign that would otherwise be present there. We therefore have a single dash in this sentence.

*) At least I can't think of any situation.